# c# linked list priority grouping

Tags: c#

So I want to create a linked list in C# not using the system built linked list class.

If I have a list of 
A-3  B-1  C-5  D-3  E-4  F-1  G-3  H-5

I want to sort that list to be like this:
F-1   B-1    G-3   D-3   A-3   E-4    H-5   C-5

Alphabets stand for book author's last name initial and the number is author's book rating.

I just need to understand how I can do priority grouping of the list items. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean as you add them, or are you sorting an existing list?  Also it would help if you could show what you have tried.

Comment: Is the list a raw string? have you used a class? What have you done so far?

Comment: Honestly a good place to start would be to read the source code behind the C# list functionality. Read it, learn it, copy it.

Comment: Can you post a sample code snippet of your list please?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a model with a property that contains A3, B1, etc.  So couldn't you simply use `GroupBy` and then iterate through?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on priority queue data structure. Description from wiki:

> In computer science, a priority queue is an abstract data type which is like a regular queue or stack data structure, but where additionally each element has a "priority" associated with it. In a priority queue, an element with high priority is served before an element with low priority. If two elements have the same priority, they are served according to their order in the queue.
>
> While priority queues are often implemented with heaps, they are conceptually distinct from heaps. A priority queue is an abstract concept like "a list" or "a map"; just as a list can be implemented with a linked list or an array, a priority queue can be implemented with a heap or a variety of other methods such as an unordered array.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). It is used for sorting by priority. You can find implementation in C5 library (`IntervalHeap` class) - https://www.nuget.org/packages/C5

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12257444)

Comment: @rsjaffe, added citation from wiki

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the normal Lined List and just sort it. Not clear if you really have string "A-1" in the lsit or if theses are objects. My guess is objects. So do:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(o=>o.Ranking);
```

assuming object is

```
public class ObjThing
{
   public string Auhtor;
   public in Ranking;
}
```

Comment: They specifically said they didn't want to use the built in list functionality.

Comment: The OP said not the LinkedList class, but didn't necessarily exclude List.